# Mssing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

There might be similar questions in SO but None helped me achieving my result and hence end up asking here.

The Scenario

I have a ViewController(HomeViewController).In my HomeController I have a subview with a tableview inside. This subview is partially visible and users can Pan it down to reveal Tableview data. The Tableview will display Notifications like Messages , Photos , Notes and Events. My application is a Group chat only app. So these Messages , photos , Notes and Events will be Displayed based on Groups. And a group will show only 25 Messages , 8 photos , 2 notes and 1 event details. Fro showing messages I have created a TableviewCell and registered it to the Tableview inside HomeViewController like this

```
var notifications : NotificationsView!
notifications.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.height + 175, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        notifications._tableview.dataSource = self
        notifications._tableview.delegate = self
        notifications._tableview.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TimelineCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "timelinecell")
        notifications._tableview.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PhotosCell",   bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "photos")
        notifications._tableview.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NotesCell",    bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "notes")
        notifications._tableview.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CalendarCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "calendar")
```

And My Model Class looks like this

```
class TimelineModal : Object {
    dynamic var groupID         = ""
    dynamic var groupName       = ""
    let messages        =   List<TimelineGroupMessages>()
    let photos          =   List<TimelineGroupPhotos>()
    let notes           =   List<TimelineGroupNotes>()
    let calendarDetails =   List<TimelineGroupCalendar>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "groupID"  }

}

class TimelineGroupMessages : Object {

    dynamic var message         = ""
    dynamic var userName        = ""
    dynamic var messagetype     = ""
}

class TimelineGroupPhotos : Object {

    dynamic var photo           = ""
}

class TimelineGroupNotes : Object {

    dynamic var noteTitle       = ""

}

class TimelineGroupCalendar : Object {

    dynamic var calendarEventDate   = ""
    dynamic var calendarEventTitle   = ""

}
```

Data inside Tableview will be such a way that each group's Messages(25) shows first then Photos(8) , then Notes (2) and finally Event (1) and again the same formatted data will show for another group.

For showing data the Data from realm is Fetched on `viewWillAppear()`

```
 private var numberofRowsforTimeline : Int = 0
    private var realmdata : Results<TimelineModal>!
    private var groupsCount : Int = 0
    private var messagesCount : Int = 0
    private var photosCount : Int = 0
    private var notesCount : Int = 0
    private var eventsCount : Int = 0

 private func LoadDatafromRealm()
    {
let realm = try! Realm()
        let realmDbData = realm.objects(TimelineModal)
        print("Data : \(realmDbData)")
        groupsCount = realmDbData.count
        let messages_Count  : Int = Int(realm.objects(TimelineGroupMessages).count)
        let photos_Count    : Int = Int(realm.objects(TimelineGroupPhotos).count)
        let notes_Count     : Int = Int(realm.objects(TimelineGroupNotes).count)
        let events_Count    : Int = Int(realm.objects(TimelineGroupCalendar).count)
        self.realmdata = realmDbData 

        numberofRowsforTimeline += messages_Count + photos_Count + notes_Count + events_Count

}
```

And here is the code where I gets the error mentioned

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberofRowsforTimeline
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell : UITableViewCell!
    // let cellMessages : TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelinecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineCell
     //let cellPhotos      : PhotosCell    = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photos", forIndexPath: indexPath)         as! PhotosCell
     //let cellNotes       : NotesCell     = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("notes", forIndexPath: indexPath)          as! NotesCell
     //let cellCalendar    : CalendarCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendar", forIndexPath: indexPath)       as! CalendarCell

        for __data in self.realmdata
        {
            if __data.messages.count > 0
            {
               let cellMessages : TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelinecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

                for x in 0..<__data.messages.count - 1
                    {
                        cellMessages.topConstraintforgroupNameLabel.constant = heightConstraints.topConstraintForRowZero.rawValue
                        cellMessages.topConstraintfortabNameLabel.constant = heightConstraints.topConstraintForRowZero.rawValue
                        cellMessages.lblGroupID.text = __data.groupID
                        cellMessages.lblGroupID.hidden = true
                        cellMessages.lblGroupName.text = __data.groupName
                        cellMessages.lblmessage.text = __data.messages[x].message
                        return cellMessages
                    }

            }
            else if __data.photos.count > 0
            {
                let cellPhotos : PhotosCell    = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photos", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! PhotosCell

                for p in 0..<__data.photos.count - 1
                {
                    cellPhotos.imgPhoto1_photos.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: __data.photos[p].photo)
                    return cellPhotos
                }
                             }
            else if __data.notes.count > 0
            {
                let cellNotes : NotesCell     = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("notes", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotesCell

                for n in 0..<__data.notes.count - 1
                {
                    cellNotes.lblNoteName1.text = __data.notes[n].noteTitle
                   return cellNotes
                }
                            }
            else if __data.calendarDetails.count > 0
            {
                let cellCalendar    : CalendarCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendar", forIndexPath: indexPath)       as! CalendarCell
                for c in 0..<__data.calendarDetails.count - 1
                {
                    cellCalendar.lblEventName1.text = __data.calendarDetails[c].calendarEventTitle
                 return cellCalendar
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return cell

            }
        }
} //-> Error  Mssing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'
```

Where i went wrong? Sorry if made my question too broad. Just tried to make sure you understand what I need. That's it. Help! Help! Help!

**Note :** I tried returning Cell in different ways where the error mentioned didn't occured but the Tableview had same data for all cell.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how the tableView delegate and datasource methods are used to build a tableView.  In particular, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called multiple times, once for each row that is to be displayed.  The indexPath parameter tells you which section/row is required.  There is no need to loop through your data - just use the indexPath to select the correct elements in your arrays.  The loops are in any event futile, since the first time the `return` statement is executed, the whole function is terminated - the loop will not progress to its next iteration.

Comment: @pbasdf  I am partially understood you... Can you please show the code for the same with my example ??? That would do better I believe...

Comment: @pbasdf How can I use indexPath to get the right elements from a multidimensional array ? I am in a bit confused state now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how the tableView delegate and datasource methods are used to build a tableView. In particular, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called multiple times, once for each row that is to be displayed. The `indexPath` parameter tells you which section/row is required. There is no need to loop through your data - just use the `indexPath` to select the correct elements in your arrays. The loops are in any event futile, since the first time the return statement is executed, the whole function is terminated - the loop will not progress to its next iteration.

For example, the following should result in a table with a section for each Group, with rows in each section for messages, photos, notes and events:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.groupsCount // separate section for each Group
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // locate the correct Group for the given section
    let __data = self.realmdata[section]
    // the total number of rows for this section (ie Group) is:
    // number of messages + number of photos + number of notes + number of events:
    return __data.messages.count + __data.photos.count + __data.notes.count + __data.calendarDetails.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // locate the correct Group for the given section (using the indexPath)
    let __data = self.realmdata[indexPath.section]
    if (indexPath.row < __data.messages.count) { // first rows are the messages
        // use the indexPath.row to get the required index for the messages:
        let messageIndex = indexPath.row
        let cellMessages : TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelinecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineCell
        cellMessages.topConstraintforgroupNameLabel.constant = heightConstraints.topConstraintForRowZero.rawValue
        cellMessages.topConstraintfortabNameLabel.constant = heightConstraints.topConstraintForRowZero.rawValue
        cellMessages.lblGroupID.text = __data.groupID
        cellMessages.lblGroupID.hidden = true
        cellMessages.lblGroupName.text = __data.groupName
        // use the index to locate the correct message text:
        cellMessages.lblmessage.text = __data.messages[messageIndex].message
        return cellMessages
    } else if (indexPath.row < __data.messages.count + __data.photos.count) { // next are the photos
        // use the indexPath.row (adjusted to account for the messages rows) to get the required index for the photos:
        let photoIndex = indexPath.row - __data.messages.count
        let cellPhotos : PhotosCell    = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photos", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! PhotosCell
        cellPhotos.imgPhoto1_photos.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: __data.photos[photoIndex].photo)
        return cellPhotos
    } else if (indexPath.row < __data.messages.count + __data.photos.count + __data.notes.count) { // next are the notes
        let noteIndex = indexPath.row - __data.messages.count - __data.photos.count
        let cellNotes : NotesCell     = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("notes", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotesCell
        cellNotes.lblNoteName1.text = __data.notes[noteIndex].noteTitle
        return cellNotes
    } else { // next are the Events
        let eventIndex = indexPath.row - __data.messages.count - __data.photos.count - __data.notes.count
        let cellCalendar    : CalendarCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendar", forIndexPath: indexPath)       as! CalendarCell
        cellCalendar.lblEventName1.text = __data.calendarDetails[eventIndex].calendarEventTitle
        return cellCalendar
    }
}
```

Comment: I owe you... :)

Comment: Everything is going fine but I have a question to ask. looking at the last else case will it work if there isn't any data in events ?

Comment: @Joker If there is no data in events, then the total number of rows will be 25+8+2+0 = 35.  Since this is the value returned by `numberOfRowsInSection`, the table view will populate rows 0-34 by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the corresponding indexPath row values.  But it will not even try to populate row 35 (the "events" row).  So the last `else` clause will not be executed.